# Android Navigation Drawer - Multiple sections

Tags: android, navigation

I am building a navigation drawer which is going to have multiple sections like below: 
[Sliding Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwkO7.png)

Physics 
    Fundamentals of Physics 
    Seven Brief Lessons on Physics 
    The New Physics 
    The Physicist's World

Subjects 
    Physics  
    Chemistry 
    Biology 
    Art

Settings 
    About  
    Logout

Section 1: Section 1 will load the list of books based on the Subject selected in section 2. By default, the list of books for first subject will be loaded. 
Section 2: Section 2 is for the list of subjects the student has subscribed. 
Section 3: Same for all students

To populate the navigation drawer UI, I have come up with a Menu Structure like below:

BookMenu 
    ArrayList of Sections

Sections 
    Section ID, 
    Section Header 
    ArrayList of Books

Books 
    bookID, 
 
    bookTitle

I am stuck on the below items: 
1. Populating the list view from adapter which takes BookMenu as input 
2. dynamically changing only the first section when subject is changed

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Note: Image attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by different view types. For Example -

```
class MyData{
    String text;
    boolean isHeader;
}
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<MyData> allData;
    class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on list(let assume 0 for header 1 for data
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        return allData.get(position).isHeader?0:1;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new ViewHolder0(header view);
             case 1: return new ViewHolder2(data view);
             ...
         }
    }
}
```

And if data is updated then just update your dataList and call notifyDataSetChange() on the adapter.

Hope it will help you :)